# Android - SSL Handshake Exception on using Volley / java code

Tags: java, android, ssl, networking, sslhandshakeexception

When trying to access web service from secured testing environment with SSL certificate getting the issue below.

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0xa35dad40: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:100000d7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSL_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:402 0xa3630912:0x00000000)
```

I have tried with volley and basic java code, still getting the same issue. When I used the same code for secured development environment with different certificate its working fine. Whereas its not working in testing environment for specific bandwidths (Airtel 3G, 4G). It is working fine with all the environments(Testing & Dev) for 2G bandwidths.

Don't know where the problem occurs. Help me in sorting out this issue.

I have added the code snippet below,

```
Responsecallback responsecallback;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    testing(mBase_Url);
}

public void testing(String urls) {

    String result = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urls);
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLCertificate()); // Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(30000);
        connection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                .appendQueryParameter("country", "IN");
        String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.println(query);
        out.close();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())); //,8192
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            result = result.concat(inputLine);
        }

        responsecallback.displayResponse(result);
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        result = e.toString();
        Log.e(TAG, "HTTP Error Result=" + result);
        responsecallback.displayResponse(result);
    }
}

private SSLSocketFactory getSSLCertificate() {
    try {
        // Get an instance of the Bouncy Castle KeyStore format
        KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        // your trusted certificates (root and any intermediate certs)
        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xxxxxx); //SSL Certificate - P12 formate
        String password = "XXXXXXX"; // Certificate password

        char[] pwd = password.toCharArray();
        try {
            trusted.load(in, pwd);
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

        kmf.init(trusted, pwd);

        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(trusted);

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), getWrappedTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

        return context.getSocketFactory();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception e=" + e.toString());
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}

private TrustManager[] getWrappedTrustManagers() {
    return new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
                        throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
                        throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
                }

                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    X509Certificate[] myTrustedAnchors = new X509Certificate[0];
                    return null;
                }
            }
    };
}
```

Comment: Post your code which is causing this error.

Comment: I have edited my query by adding code snippet for your reference.

Comment: Why are you returning null from `getAcceptedIssuers`?

Comment: It does not affect the response even if it returns null or any other value.